# printf format character from getchar() in C

Tags: c, char, getchar

I have a task is to print the ASCII code number and the input:
Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  char ch;
  printf("Whatever: ");
  while((ch = getchar()) != 'q')
  {
    getchar();
    printf("The char is %c and %d in ASCII.\n", ch, ch);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What should I revise if I want to print the \n from the getchar() function?

```
Example: 
  The char is \n and 10 in ASCII.
```

Comment: You can compare the ch with the newline character and if it is true, use`\\n` inside the `printf`

Comment: 1) Enable all warnings 2) `char ch;` --> `int ch;` to avoid troubles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope below helps

```
while((ch = getchar()) != 'q')
{
   if(ch == '\n')
        printf("The '\\n' ascii value is %d\n", ch);
   else
        printf("The '%c' ascii value is %d\n", ch, ch);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is a good way to do it. however, I wonder if I would like to print other format character like \a \b, is there any better idea to do that?

Comment: Those are non printable characters you have to compare them with their ascii code [ascii table](https://www.asciitable.com/) and print the same way as we are printing `\n`